# Sending message from ActiveMQ Artemis to ActiveMQ "Classic"

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ **Artemis** (N1) for my work, and recently I've got a task to send some messages to another ActiveMQ "Classic" (N2) which is used by another system. However, I don't know how should I write divert configurations at `broker.xml` file. Is it possible? Could you give an example of divert to another URL-address and queue. Where should I write login/password for connection to N2?

Answer (score 1):

[Diverts](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html) in ActiveMQ Artemis only work with **local** resources. To send messages to another instance of ActiveMQ Artemis you'd use a [core bridge](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/core-bridges.html). However, that *only* works between instances of ActiveMQ Artemis. ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't support the protocol which the core bridge uses.

In order to send messages from ActiveMQ Artemis to ActiveMQ "Classic" you'd need to use something like Camel or the [JMS bridge](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-bridge.html) shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis. Both of these solutions can be deployed as web applications using the embedded web application server in ActiveMQ Artemis. We ship examples of both. The Camel example is in `examples/features/standard/camel/` and the JMS bridge example is in `examples/submodules/inter-broker-bridge`.